# Is it necessary to run tests in all environments?

Tags: testing, mongodb

In our project, we have DEV, STG and PRD environments that are configured to mirror each other (especially STG and PRD). We have unit tests that we run on DEV and, if they pass, are moved to STG when we have code changes. A similar process is used to move code from STG to PRD.

A lot of these tests involve DB operations though our API, but some involve logic. My question is, **is it necessary to run the tests in the STG and PRD environments when they have already passed in the DEV environment?**

This is relevant because we are using MongoDB and are considering using MongoDB Memory Server to run the tests (because of the speed and the ability to keep junk data out of the DBs), rather than running the tests against our actual MongoDB instances.

What are the best practices in such a situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create tests to prove that something works correctly, and you re-execute those tests to prove that it *still* works correctly.

For determining if it makes sense to run a particular set of tests in multiple environments, you need to check what the differences are between those environments and if those differences might have an effect on the outcome of the tests.

One important aspect to look at is the codebase being used in each environment. If the DEV environment uses a feature branch or even the code a developer has locally and the STG is the first environment where multiple features can meet each other, then it is important to execute the unittests in both environments, as they each have a different codebase that was not yet tested in another environment.

On the other hand, if the integrated code is already tested in the DEV environment, then the reason "untested codebase" does not exist for running those tests in the STG environment.

Testing in a PRD (production) environment should be restricted to a simple test that the configuration is correct, or tests that require a lot of data to be gathered from end-users like A/B testing. All other tests should have been performed on the other environments before the code reached PRD.

Comment: Testing in a PRD (production) environment may be useful if there is more then one server, so the new version is tested before the upgraded surver is added to the load balance system.

Comment: Nowadays there's no manual "server added to the load balancer". It's automatic and you don't even notice it happened. Because if you test PRD, you do it through the load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's make sure that we use the same names:

> We have unit tests that we run on DEV

Unit test should be independent of any environment: No database, message queue or external environment. You should ideally try to make a lot of this cheap and fast test. Some integration test may use an in memory database or TestContainers with test data that is independent of your environments. That helps to check when you have broke the code from when changes in the environment have broke the integration.

But even with the best unit test suite you may find that there is value in other types: integration, end-to-end, exploratory, etc. This new level of test will surely be slower and more expensive as you need environments, apis, databases, mailserver, proxys...
Here you really want to reduce the waste of testing three times if possible. You want to select only those tests affected when the environment has a different:

- Data size -> Re test performance of queries or long batch tasts.
- Data structure: tables, old versions of the data, abnormal cases due to bugs.
- Configurations -> Re test tasks affected by configuration.
- Other systems (apis, microservices, etc).

But there won't be any benefit to duplicate a test for the inner logic contained in your module or to test that you can reconnect to mongo in case of network failure. Rather than doing the same tests again explore how the new features works in the new environment with an open mind.

In the long run you may still want to minimice this environment differences to avoid the waste of retesting and discovering a bug to late. Your Dev and Stg environments should have cases of the old data and ideally with the same size and configuration. Calls to other services can use api contracts to make sure that they are still compatible. Changes in the database is always a tricky question and depends on how do you evolve. If you are in the microservice world you own the database structure and have in under version control. MongoDB is a bit specific as it can have unstructured data. Is testing in Production a way to test against production data? May be you would like to force an schema.

Some component may still be different in production like the payment gateway. So you may want to check in production everytime you make any changes to the payment module or your provider upgrades the gateway.

Finally, with the arrival of microservices and containers there are a long list of patterns to test in production. But they are still different ways of testing: canary releases, green/blue, dark launch... This tests bring real user's interactions that can surprise you in interesting ways.

P.S. Remember that the desired level of testing depends on the context. Do you handle money? Do you handle medical records? how important is a bug? How complex is the logic?

Comment: I appreciate the thoughtful response. You have mentioned good things to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is supposed to be tested before it enters production. That is the whole point of your test effort. Unit tests are meaningful in development, you run those before you commit code to your version control system.

Now the behavior of your application may depend on the moon phase which could make it beneficial to continuously run tests in production so that when something falls over you will know soon and you can panic in time. But that sounds weird, does it not?

Comment: thx for the interesting analogy!